# Cursor vs CursorLoader

Tags: android, cursor, out-of-memory, android-cursorloader, android-loadermanager

Ok i'm confused. What is the difference between the two? I've been working with a pre-made database imported in the assets folders and been using images in my listview and been getting errors about outofmemory while scrolling down. I read different ways to handle it, but can really understand some tutorials, then i read something about cursorloader and loadermanager something and that it can solve my problem on the outofmemory error. Is that how it really work? I saw alot of tutorials but mostly points out to data insertion so i got confused.

Answer (score 2):

As per [this definition from Techopedia](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/27387/cursor-databases):

> A database cursor is an object used to pinpoint records in a database. Just like a typing cursor is used to alert you where your text will appear, a database cursor also shows you the specific record in a database that is being worked upon.

Whereas, [CursorLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html) is an Android API that is used to interact with a [ContentProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html) *asynchronously*. By asynchronously I mean, it can do the query in a background thread without blocking the main thread (also called the UI thread). After querying, it will retrieve the result from ContentProvider and reconnect to the Activity on the main thread.

I think, the Out-of-Memory issue that you're facing is clearly answered here: [Strange out of memory issue while loading an image to a Bitmap object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object)

Comment: Thanks :) Got that out of my system. xD